# Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed in Service manager

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a windows service manager, I try to stop the service by the manager. However I got the exception:

```
Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed

    private static void StopService()
    {
        if (!IsInstalled()) return;
        try
        {
            CFEServiceController c = new CFEServiceController();
            c.StopService(ServiceName, 500);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in Stop service " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And:

```
public void StopService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        using (ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName))
        {
            try
            {
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
                if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                {
                    service.Stop();
                    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
                    Console.WriteLine("Stop service " + serviceName+" ");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error when stop service in code StopService " + ex.Message); // here I got the exception
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because of this:

```
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
```

This is happening because your service has not stopped within your `timeout`. You should either set your timeout higher, or don't set a timeout at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try open

> "Event Viewer" -> "Windows Logs" -> "Application"

There could be Error Level message that could give you a clue if increasing/unset the number of timeout doesn't help as answered by @gleng.